# xpages validation

Tags: validation, xpages

This is probably very simple I'm trying to add a validation based on another field
In formula language :
     @If(Desinfect_1 = "" & Desinfect = "Désinfection de chambre" ;@Failure("Veuillez cocher départ ou levée");@Success)

In Xpages I've tried with the validation expression :

```
<xp:inputText value="#{document1.chambre}" id="chambre1">
<xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent ("Desinfect1").getValue() ==    "Désinfection de chambre"}]]></xp:this.rendered>
<xp:this.validators>
<xp:validateExpression
message="err">
<xp:this.expression><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (GetComponent ("Desinfect1").getValue() == "Désinfection de chambre" & GetComponent ("Chambre1").getValue() == ""){
return false;
} 
else {
return true;
}}]]></xp:this.expression>
</xp:validateExpression>
</xp:this.validators>
</xp:inputText>
```

Comment: Sorry, but what's the problem / your question?

Comment: BTW: SSJS is case sensitiv. GetComponent will not work. Use getComponent instead ;-)

Comment: The probleme is that the validation is not working I'll try the getComponent

Comment: I tried with the correct syntax :

Comment: but no luck my code now looks like <xp:this.validators>
 <xp:validateExpression message="err">
 <xp:this.expression>
 <![CDATA[#{javascript:
 if (getComponent("Desinfect1").getValue() == "Désinfection de chambre" & getComponent("Chambre1").getValue() == ""){
   return false;
   } 
   else {
   return true;
  }}]]></xp:this.expression>
</xp:validateExpression>
</xp:this.validators>

Comment: Remember to use && as the logical AND operator

Comment: I noticed that after Sven's comment - but its still not working

Comment: Thanks for all your assistance - You saved me alot of time, by pointing me in the right direction.  Finally my problem was with the getComponent("Chambre1") it should have been getComponent("chambre1").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding some print outs to see are you getting the correct values for the fields

Answer (score 2):

When you are doing the logical operator for AND in javascript you must use &&

```
<xp:this.validators>
    <xp:validateExpression message="err">
        <xp:this.expression> 
            <![CDATA[#{javascript: if (getComponent("Desinfect1").getValue() == "Désinfection de chambre" && getComponent("Chambre1").getValue() == ""){ return false; } else { return true; }}]]> 
        </xp:this.expression> 
    </xp:validateExpression> 
</xp:this.validators>
```